# access denied for root user

Tags: root, gimp, directory

I cannot save my .gih file into */usr/share/gimp/2.0/brushes/* directory. I encounter with *"access denied"* message though I am a root user. What must I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to the last answer you shouldn't run graphical applications using `sudo`. The preferred method is to use either `gksu` or `gksudo`. Use `sudo` when running terminal applications or performing other actions in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

No need to run gimp with admin privileges, save it in a folder inside your home folder, open a terminal and type

```
sudo cp ~/<path to file> /usr/share/gimp/2.0/brushes/
```

to copy the file to that folder, or

```
sudo mv ~/<path to file> /usr/share/gimp/2.0/brushes/
```

to move the file to that folder.